# Swift / perform multiple actions on snapshot

Tags: ios, swift

I have a snapshot of my Viewcontroller,

```
...
let fromView = transitionContext.viewForKey(UITransitionContextFromViewKey)!
...
snapshot = fromView.snapshotViewAfterScreenUpdates(true)
...
container!.addSubview(snapshot!)
...
```

I want to perform a move AND a size change.

```
    let moveDown = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(200, container!.frame.height - 600)        
    let minimalize = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.6, 0.6)
```

But calling both:

```
            self.snapshot?.transform = moveDown
            self.snapshot?.transform = minimalize
```

Only executes one of the transformations.
If the moveDown performs last, it moves down, if minimalize -> minimalize.

How can I perform two tranformations after another?

I'm sure my issue is, that the snapshot hasn's changed, it is always the "source" snapshot, that's why only the last one will take action. But how can I save a snapshot of the "new" snapshot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `transform` property doesn't permanently modify the original data, it only transforms it as long as that property is set.  So, you can only use one transform at a time.  However, you can make a transform do many things at once.  Instead of making two separate transforms, one that moves and one that scales, make one that does both:

```
let moveDown = CGAffineTransformMakeTranslation(200, container!.frame.height - 600)
let moveDownAndScale = CGAffineTransformScale(moveDown, 0.6, 0.6)

self.snapshot?.transform = moveDownAndScale
```

The trick is to use `CGAffineTransformScale` as opposed to `CGAffineTransformMakeScale`.  The later creates an entirely new transform while the former applies a scale to an existing transform.